# how to search record from Sql Server DataBase?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am trying to search the record from SqlServer 2008 which includes three tables and want to display all item from that specific search item, and the requested search item is an primary key, so it is available at-least in one table from all of three.
how can i achieve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry can you please reformulate your question?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm